# Admin access filter

Tags: yii

I have been having this weird experience with my Yii app. I created an account '**admin**' and this admin created an additional admin account called '**sample**'. Now **sample**, is successfully created and added to the authassignment table as an admin. Here is proof that user 204 is an admin.

[image]

Checkuser access also proves to be true that the **sample** account is an admin. But somehow, accessing the admin functions of a certain controller returns error 403 when logged in as **sample** but the other admin account **admin**, user 0 access it fine. Here's the access rule of the controller.

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view','update'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','dynamicUnitName'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

What is wrong with my app and why is it acting this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `roles` instead of `users`. `users` holds the names of users. For more information look at the [Yii page on access control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter)

```
array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
    'actions'=>array('admin','delete','dynamicUnitName'),
    'roles' => array("admin"),
),
```

Comment: Ah. I get it. Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete','dynamicUnitName'),
        'users'=>array('admin'),
    ),
```

To

```
    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete','dynamicUnitName'),
        'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->role == "admin"',
    ),
```